# VS2008 on Windows 7 RTM with x64 compiler broken

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, 64-bit

I am having trouble getting x64 compilation to work on Windows 7 RTM (64-bit) with Visual Studio 2008 Professional (both with and without SP1). I have not installed the Windows 7 SDK, as [Microsoft suggests might be the issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2009/06/15/installing-win-7-sdk-rc-and-vs2008-rtm-can-disable-vc-configuration-platform-choices.aspx). The problem is that there are no x64/64-bit choices in the Configuration Manager of Visual Studio.

I do not have the "Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2008 Standard Edition" suggested in the link above installed on my computer. Any ideas what might fix this?

I have checked that I have the x64 compiler and tools installed with Visual Studio.

**Solution found**: Uninstall VS completely and reinstall. Issue resolved after SP1 installed (again). Very strange.

Comment: Are you trying to cross compile from x86, or is this on a x64 OS?

Comment: The OS is 64-bit. Updated the question with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VS 2008 Express Edition?

You can add the x64 targets to the build configuration manually by downloading the Windows SDK (which include all the x64 compilers/linkers/libs/headers/... ) and following the instructions in this link:

http://jenshuebel.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/visual-c-2008-express-edition-and-64-bit-targets/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Did you make sure to include the 64 bit toolset as part of the Visual Studio install?   This toolset is an optional component that can be disabled during the initial install process.  I believe you can add it back in by going through a Visual Studio repair process.

**Original Answer**

Are you using a clean windows 7 RTM install or did you upgrade from a previous version?  There is at least one issue being reported by Visual Studio customers who upgraded an earlier build of Windows 7 to RTM.

Other, seemingly unrelated issue

- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VistaUsersUninstallVisualStudio2010Beta1BeforeUpgradingToWindows7.aspx

Comment: This was a clean install of Windows 7 RTM. No other version of VS has been installed.

Comment: A solution was found, but I did have to 64-bit toolset installed when trying.